# Do I have to reorganize plans every season?

Tags: medieval-dynasty

One can define a plan for what to do in a building, i.e. harvesting [mushrooms](https://medieval-dynasty.fandom.com/wiki/Mushrooms). Most mushrooms are only available during Autumn.

When desinging a plan, you have to distribute the percentage points up to 100%.
Now, I want my worker to harvest mushrooms and herbs.
The mushrooms I want only grow during autumn, the herbs I want only grow during spring and summer.
[image: example of 3 items, one available this season, the others not]

Do I have to redo the plan every season for maximum efficency or are the points distributed on undoable things (like mushroons in spring) automatically counted towards the other things?

Regarding the example picture, assuming these are the only 3 options, would changing the %-values to 0%, 0%, 28% change the actual yield?

The [newest information I found](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1129580/discussions/0/2950411088487246543/) is from Sept '21 and I found no hint in the changesets.